# CQL filter multiple typenames to retrieve features within specified geometry

Tags: geospatial, cql, geoserver, geo

**Environment**

I'm trying to fetch featuredata from a WFS layer running on GeoServer using CQL filtering. I have no access to the server.

**Goal**

Receive all features of two types within the geometry of another feature of another layer; with at most one request per layer (thus not per type)

**Train of thought**

I have to:

- Receive geometry from a wfs layer (geometryA)
- Use this geometry to receive two typenames from another layer with geometry within "geometryA".

**Attempts**

For a single typename it would be easy. First fetch geometryA, then:

`https://src/wfs?request=getFeature&version=2.0.0&typenames=namespace:typename&srsName=EPSG:28992&outputFormat=application/json&cql_filter=WITHIN(geometry, geometryA)`

But I can't get it figured out for multiple type names... I've tried:

`https://src/wfs?request=getFeature&version=2.0.0&typenames=namespace:typename;namespace:typename2&srsName=EPSG:28992&outputFormat=application/json&cql_filter=WITHIN(geometry, geometryA)`

which results in:

`Extracted invalid join sub-filter [ geometrie within POLYGON ((154884 463434, 154884 463455,
      154905 463455, 154905 463434, 154884 463434)) ], it users more than one feature type + []`

So I've tried, after some googling,

`https://src/wfs?request=getFeature&version=2.0.0&typenames=namespace:typename;namespace:typename2&srsName=EPSG:28992&outputFormat=application/json&cql_filter=WITHIN(geometry, geometryA);WITHIN(geometry, geometryA)`

which results in:

`Join query must specify a filter`

And now I'm quite lost...

**Question**

Would anyone be able to tell me how to use CQL (or anything else) to retreive two typenames within a fixed geometry?

Answer (score 1):

In WFS 2.0 specifying 2 (or more) `typeNames` introduces a [join in the query](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html#108). This will return tuples of the types joined according to the filter you supply.

In your case I'm not entirely clear if that is what you want, if it isn't then you can just make 2 requests for the single types (in parallel for speed?).

If it is what you want, you can avoid the ambiguity of `geometrie` being an attribute of both types by adding an alias to the types, so your query becomes something like:

```
  <wfs:Query typeNames="namespace:typename;namespace:typename2" aliases="a b" >
     <fes:Filter>
        <fes:Or>
        <fes:Within>
           <fes:ValueReference>a.geometrie</fes:PropertyName>
           <fes:Literal>POLYGON ((154884 463434, 154884 463455,
  154905 463455, 154905 463434, 154884 463434))</fes:Literal>
        </fes:Within>
        <fes:Within>
           <fes:ValueReference>b.geometrie</fes:PropertyName>
           <fes:Literal>POLYGON ((154884 463434, 154884 463455,
  154905 463455, 154905 463434, 154884 463434))</fes:Literal>
        </fes:Within>
       </fes:Or>
     </fes:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
```

I'm not sure that you can create that sort of join by using CQL but you could try it as:

```
cql_filter=WITHIN(a.geometry, geometryA) OR WITHIN(b.geometry, geometryA)
```